# SESSIONID is not getting stored in Cookie in an application with Angular 6 as frontend and spring boot as backend

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, redis

I am building a simple Q&A website. The frontend is Angular 6 and the backend is Spring Boot. I am also using spring security with Redis to store sessions. I have a couple of questions.

1. When a user login I see the response from the server contains a SetCookie: Session: XXXXX in the response header but on a subsequent call, never has session attribute set in the HEADER. I also checked the Cookie in the application tab in the inspect mode of Chrome. No value is set. However, If I set anything in the localStorage. I can see it there.

Login code

```
login.component.ts (This is called once the user press login)

       this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    // this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });


AuthenticationService


export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(emailId: string, password: string) {


        const headers = new HttpHeaders(
            emailId && password ? {
              authorization:'Basic ' + btoa(emailId + ':' + password)
            }:{}
          );

        return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/login`, {headers:headers})
            .pipe(map(user => {

                if (user ) { 

                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    console.log("user is " + JSON.stringify(user));
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }
```

SpringBoot

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("*********Authorizing in websecurityconfig*********");
        http.cors().and()
                //starts authorizing configurations
                .authorizeRequests()
                //ignoring the guest urls...
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/error","/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/logout", "POST"))
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/users/login").and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

REST API

```
  @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?>  getStudentDetailById (Principal principal) throws Exception{

        final String emailId = principal.getName();
        try {
            ValidationUtil.validate(emailId);
            logger.info("Email id is " + emailId);
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
            logger.info("Exception = {} occurred", e);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(principal.getName());
    }
```

Here is the SESSION in login response received from the server

Set-Cookie: SESSION=YjBjODE2MjQtMGQxOC00ZmU1LWI2MmMtOTg5YzkwM2FjY2Fm; Path=/; HttpOnly

After login, suppose I want to invoke another API on the same server/another server. The request does not contain the session detail.

What I am missing.

2. I would like to have clarification between the functionality of the SESSIONID received and the advantage of storing userid in localStorage.

My Question

I want to get Questions posted by a user after he/she logs in. So, I need his/her userid in the response after login. So, after login, I am storing userid in localStorage. Then what is the use of SESSIONID? Is it just to make sure that subsequent request to server does not have to be authenticated again and again as the spring security will use SESSIONID to allow the user to use other resources. If yes, then will the spring security will verify each request for SESSIONID (I think so).

Comment: Are you serving Angular and Spring from the same server? E.g. is Spring serving your static Angular build or is the Angular build served from a different server?

Comment: @NateVaughan
both are running on different servers.

Angluar: localhost:4200
SpringBoot: localhost:8080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my answers for you.

### Setting cookie in your browser

When you want your browser to create a cookie when it received the `Set-Cookie` header in the response, you might need to tell the browser to be ready to accept such a behavior. By default, your browser does not store a Cookie if it was not suppose to. You have to change to `get` this way :

```
return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/login`, {headers:headers, withCredentials: true})
```

Once you have done that, there is 2 scenarios possible:

- Either your frontend and your backend share the same root (http://localhost for instance), then you should be good, and not be concerned about **CORS**...
- Or, your frontend URL is `http://myfrontend.com/` and your backend is `http://mybackend.com`, and in this case, you will experience what is a `preflight` request made by your browser, and some **CORS** issue, that your backend server is automatically enabling to avoid any attacks... See this:  [Angular 2 cookie not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166754/angular-2-cookie-not-set)

Like you said in one of your comment, your server will want to make sure the client requesting your endpoint is allowed. You can accept a CORS Origin request with a global configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

### SESSIONID versus LocalStorage

Both things are both similar and different.

Similar:

- Both can be used to authenticate your user

Different:

- You don't authenticate the user the same way.

**SESSION ID**

They are used to stored your user information on the server. Basically, the server stores a map of  to keep some context :

- Are you authenticated ?
- Have you done this action ?
- Do you have any things you want me to hold for you ?

But it is all in the server... In the recent architecture, **microservices**, you don't want to allow the server to store information because you can't ensure that your client, by doing the same request twice, will call the same server... This to make sure you have a resident system, or you need to deploy more service because there is suddenly a pic of activity... Anyway, this is old school, but works fine when you know your client will talk to only one server.

The SESSION_ID is stored in a cookie, accessible only by HTTP, which means you can not read the cookie value from your javascript code... It is protected this way. And it is your browser that is in charge of sending that cookie to the server.

Each server has its own instance of the SESSION maps... It is not shared, and therefor, server1 does not have the same SESSION maps as server2... which is a big problem in a system where you don't know how servers you can have at the same time.

**Local storage**
Something that works well for **microservices architecture** is giving the possibility to the client to carry is own authentication information, in a **Token**. This way, you can have 1, 2 or 25 server to talk too, your client will be authenticated the same way. But this token has to sent at every you make to the server. Now the thing is **How do I store the token and send it to the server ?**

You have 2 options (even more, but let's consider only 2) :

- You store this in your local storage: `localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));`. But a local storage is vulnerable to XSS attack... an hacker could steal your token information, and then use it to authenticate to the website and doing things for you, or accessing some private data. [For more information on XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)

So localStorage is perfect to store non-sensitive user date, and making the client holding its internal state... But it can be dangerous to use when storing the sensitive data, like a token.

The solution ? Use a `HTTP ONLY cookie` to store the client's token. It is different than the SESSION_ID, because it is still your client holding the authentication information, but it secured and protected from being accessed by any bad javascript code.

Hope it answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The second part makes sense. However, for the first part of the question after using the withCredentials: true. It's giving Cors issue even the domain is same ie localhost and I am already using @CrossOrigin annotation over the API in the controller not sure why. Working on it.

Comment: Have you checked the link I've sent in the first part of my answer ?

Comment: @TringTring, check my update, see if it fits your need

Comment: I had WebMvcConfigurer in my code but it seemed it was not working. The code that you have provided worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: If it worked for you, please Mark the answer and upvote, good way to say thank you and it might help others

Comment: Upvote does not work for me. The cors problem is gone. The session problem is not completely resolved but I can see Cookie is getting set (I might be doing something wrong). so was not marking it right. I was just waiting to make it work and making your reply right. 

thanks for an in-depth explanation. I apologize for not making it right answer right away.